# After updating series with api response dynamically the Highcharts Angular is not showing properly

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

After the HTTP call, the high
chart option series is getting updated but it's not showing all the data on the view. Any points are appreciated

Comment: Hi @Shreyas, Could you provide more details about the problem? It would be great if you could reproduce the issue in some online code editor. You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-service-2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.